# mod_usertrack/mod_rewrite doesn't pass cookie to downstream apps on first request

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, apache2.2

I have apache configuration like

```
CookieTracking On

<Proxy balancer://my-cluster>
    BalancerMember http://my-server:8084 loadfactor=1 ping=10 ttl=300 timeout=120
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /mystuff balancer://my-cluster
ProxyPassReverse /mystuff balancer://my-cluster
```

But the cookie doesn't get passed to `my-server` on the first invocation. Subsequent invocations are fine. I'm guessing that this is because `CookieTracking` sets the cookie on the response, not the request.

Similar behaviour if I use `mod_rewrite` with `mod_unique_id` to ape what `mod_usertrack` does:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*tracking_id.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/ - [CO=tracking_id:%{ENV:UNIQUE_ID}:%{HTTP_HOST}:525600:/]
```

Is there anyway to add a cookie so that it will appear in the request cookies for downstream apps

Is it even possible to log the cookie that I've just created. This doesn't work (presumably again because `C` refers to request cookies)

```
LogFormat "%{tracking_id}C"
```